# "Parameter count mismatch" error during adding Entity Framework migration under .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-2.0

After migration of my project to .NET Core 2.0, fresh install of Visual Studio 15.5 and .NET CORE sdk 2.1.2, I am having an error when trying to add a migration using EF Core.

```
C:\Projects\SQLwallet\SQLwallet>dotnet ef migrations add IdentityServer.
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'.
Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Parameter count mismatch.


Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'
```

As a result an empty migration class is created, with empty Up() and Down() methods.

The program.cs looks like:

```
public class Program
{

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args, string environmentName)
    {...}

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        IWebHost host;
        host = BuildWebHost(args, "Development");
```

Please advise. The migration worked fine while on Core 1.0. I have a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implemented, and my DBContext class has a parameterless constructor, so it could not be the reason.

Comment: You can safely ignore the message. It will go away when issue [#9076](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9076) is resolved.

Comment: The problem is that the migration is not generating properly, it is empty.

Answer (score 10):

My solution is to pass Array to `HasData` function, not generic `List`.
If you use List, try to convert array with `ToArray` function.

Here is an example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      var users = new List<User>();
      var user1 = new User() { Id = 1, Username = "user_1" };
      var user2 = new User() { Id = 2, Username = "user_2" };

      users = new List<User>() { user1, user2 };
      modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(users.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, thank you. Any idea why it doesn't work with generic lists?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext. Make sure it calls `base.OnModelCreating(builder)`. It should look something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);            

        builder.Entity<T>().HasData(...);
    }
```

If you are using `builder.Entity<T>().HasData(...)` to seed your data, make sure you pass it a T[] and not an IEnumerable.

Comment: Very helpful: "If you are using builder.Entity<T>().HasData(...) to seed your data, make sure you pass it a T[] and not an IEnumerable"